# Laravel with() relationship if record exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Imagine this simple query.

```
User::with(['company' => function ($query) use($request) {
      $query->where('companies.name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%');
}])->get();
```

This may return something like the below collection if the specified company doesn't exist.

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "company": null
        }
    ],
```

The query runs and returns a collection even if the company value is `null`. The problem is that in this situation I don't want record to be returned. I only want records where "company" is not null.

How can I implement this in to my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `->with(["company" => function(){ ... }])` doesn't filter the parent `User` query based on the logic, it simply limits what's returned in the `company` relationship. To limit AND filter, you need to use `->whereHas()` in conjucntion with `->with()`:

```
User::with(["company"])->whereHas("company", function($query) use($request){
    $query->where("companies.name", "like", "%".$request->name."%");
})->get();
```

In some cases, you may need to duplicate the logic in `->whereHas()` to the function in `->with()`, but since you're limiting the query results based on the relationship, you shouldn't have to.

Comment: Would you need `companies.name` or could you just use `name`?

Comment: Depends; sometimes there may be a join or other logic that causes a column like `name` to be ambiguous. In this case, yes, just `name` would likely be ok.